# grails one-to-many dynamic form submitting

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have the following domains in my application:

```
class Sport implements Serializable {

    Set terms

    static hasMany = [terms: Term]

    static mapping = {
        terms cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Term implements Serializable {
    String term
    String tagCode
    Sport sport

    static constraints = {

        sport nullable: false

    }
    static belongsTo = [sport: Sport]
    static mapping = {
        table "terms"
        sport cascade: "save-update,merge"
    }

}
```

and SportController update method:

```
 @Transactional
    def update(Sport sport) {
        def sportInstance = sportService.update(sport)
        ....
    }
```

And I also have edit.gsp where I can dynamically add/delete terms via JavaScripts and I have the following naming convention for them:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <g:textField id="term${i}" name="terms[${i}].term"
          required=""
          value="${term?.term}"/>
   </li>
   <li>
        <g:textField id="synonym${i}"
          name="terms[${i}].synonym"
          value="${term?.synonym}"/>

   </li> 
</ul>
```

When I add new term and submit edit.gsp it all goes normally: within SportController.update() method sport.terms Set contains new Term instance and there are no problems with it. But when I delete one term from the edit page and submit the page then within SportController.update() method sport.terms Set still contains Term instance which was deleted on the page. I'm sure that this Term instance is not submitted (I checked request and It didn't contain it) so I suspect that Grails is fetching it along with Sport instance somehow but I don't ask to do this. Maybe you have similar experience? Could you help me with this, please? I've already spent about 5 hours resolving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to turn `Set terms` into `List terms`, that makes GORM delete and re-create the collection upon every `save()`